# Phalcon: How to use Phalcon\Debug, but control the output for development/production environment?

Tags: php, error-handling, phalcon

I have a small application on the specified framework. I want to control what the user sees if my application fails. This should not be a standard web server response, which it is differently displayed by different browsers. In this regard, I want to use Falcon\Debug. But, as far as I understand, this component of the framework will always show something like this:

[image]

However, I would like to show this information only if debugging is enabled in my application (using an environment variable, for example). In other cases I would like to show just a page describing the error.

Question: how to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

This is my implementation in the index.php file:

```
try {
    $root = str_replace('\\', '/', dirname(dirname(__FILE__))) . '/';
    require_once $root . 'apps/Bootstrap.php';
    $bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
    $bootstrap->run();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    if (DEV_MODE === true) {
        $debug = new \Phalcon\Debug();
        die($debug->listen()->onUncaughtException($e));
    } else {
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
        // Your fancy error page for users here!
        die();
    }
}
```

The idea is to have a variable somewhere in your config files which you can easily switch between true/false.

**Update!**

You can add this too:

```
if (DEV_MODE  === true) {
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
} else {
    error_reporting(0);
}
```

Comment: The proposed option is obvious. But is there really no more native solution for my task? Nevertheless, thanks for the answer!

Comment: Ah you reminded me about the time when I fought with Dispatcher and its Events, and failed to make 500 error pages work. Succeeded with 404's tho.. Maybe you should take a look at Dispatcher class and see if you can implement it now. Will take a look again when I have some free time. Good luck for now!

Answer (score 1):

Complementing the proposal solution by Nikolay Mihaylov, **maybe you want to redirect to a specific view** and so not show blank page or default error 500 in browser, thereforce, only need add the NameSpace at the beginning

> use Phalcon\Http\Response

and redirect in catch block, here a little example:

```
try {

    // some code

} catch (\Exception $e) {

    // ... some code

    $response = new Response();

    // Redirect...
    $response->redirect('controller/view'); // for example, you could create a view to show error 500

    // Send response to the client
    $response->send();
}
```